# jmeter wont run !Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation"

Tags: java, jmeter

I installed java from the offical java download page https://java.com/en/download/win10.jsp

It installed what appears to be a 32bit on my 64 bit system, which I can only guess is OK, as it did not present any other options.

I edited my system environtment variables, and added JAVA_HOME and added %JAVA_HOME%\bin to my "user variables" Path definition.

typing "set" in a cmd window produces:

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151
:
Path=C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;.....C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin;
```

At the command prompt, "java -version"

produces:

```
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

But when I try to launch jmeter.bat, I get:

jmeter wont run !Not able to find Java executable or version. Please check your Java installation"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

1. If possible move your JRE to folder which doesn't have spaces in its path.
2. If for some reason it is not possible - surround path to "bin" folder of your JRE installation with [quotation marks](https://serverfault.com/questions/349179/path-variable-and-quotation-marks-windows)
3. In any case you should be able to run JMeter as:

   ```
   java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar
   ```

See [Setting the JAVA_HOME Variable in Windows](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html) for more details.

---

I would strongly recommend switching to 64-bit server JRE as [on 32-bit one you won't be able to allocate more than 4 GB to JMeter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#gc_heap_32bit) which might be not enough when it comes to high loads.

Check out [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) and [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) articles for more information on tuning JMeter for maximum performance

Answer (score 3):

Your Java home is connected to JRE and not JDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151). See [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/jmeter_environment.htm):

> Windows:   Set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25

It should be connected to C:...\jdk[version] path, so set JAVA_HOME as:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_151
```

Comment: For others searching, on OS X this looks like:

`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/[JDK VERSION]/Contents/Home`

Replace `[JDK VERSION]` with your installed version of java.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add `JAVA_HOME "c:\Users\User\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_322"` to System variables, but in my case I had to add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to `PATH` System variable as well. As a result - I can you orignal jmeter.bat file.

Answer (score 0):

Check-out [this article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html), best way to set JAVA_HOME. The long and short of it, if using Windows, download the JDK, open your command prompt and type in the following command: 
`setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_XX"`. Normally, the JDK is stored in your C:\Program Files\Java...

Comment: It could be C:\Progra~2

Answer (score 0):

For a straightforward and uncomplicated solution, follow this link and proceed with the download.

For Java 11
https://corretto.aws/downloads/latest/amazon-corretto-11-x64-windows-jdk.msi